# Exponential of a vector field on a manifold and diffeomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, diffeomorphism

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a manifold and $f$ be a vector field on $\mathcal{M}$. Let $\exp f = \phi(1)$ where $\phi$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
    \phi(0) &= \mathrm{id}_\mathcal{M} \\
    \dot{\phi}(t) &= f \circ \phi(t)
\end{align*}

Under what conditions is $\exp f$ a [$C^r$ diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Definition)? What are the smoothness constraints that need to be imposed on $f$? Conversely, if $f$ is $C^r$, what can we say about $\exp f$?